# How can I make this Jquery filter not case sensitive?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a filter for a html list box.  The listbox is populated from a mysql database and loads everything correctly.  I have a text box that I type into and the list filters based exactly on what is typed. I really need this to NOT be case sensitive.  In other words as it is if I enter a capitol A  the function returns all entries that begin with capitol A I need it to return all entries that begin with a regardless of capitalization.

This is the function

```
$('#custsearch').keyup(function () {
var valThis = this.value;
    lenght  = this.value.length;

$('.cust').each(function () {
    var text  = $(this).text(),
        textL = text,
        htmlR = '<b>' + text.substr(0, lenght) + '</b>' + text.substr(lenght);
    (textL.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).html(htmlR).show() : $(this).hide();
});
```

});

Comment: Did you try to convert to LowerCase first using javascript `.toLowerCase()`?

Answer (score 3):

Convert both values into lowercase using **[`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)** then compare them

```js
$('#custsearch').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = this.value,
    length = valThis.length;
  $('.cust').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      text = $this.text(),
      htmlR = '<b>' + text.substr(0, length) + '</b>' + text.substr(lenght);
    (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(valThis.toLowerCase()) == 0) ? $this.html(htmlR).show(): $this.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: `length = this.value.length;` is better as `length = valThis.length.trim()`, one more thing you can do is caching `this` reference inside `each`

Comment: in that case `valThis = this.value.trim(),`

Comment: Thank you so much this worked as soon as I fixed the aforementioned typo.  GREAT work thank you.

Comment: @PranavCBalan You're accessing the value from the DOM element reference, there's no need to access it again when you can access it from a local variable